# Scala immutable.Map.apply is re-evaluated each time it is called

Tags: scala

I am confused by the `Map.apply` API. You can easily reproduce the problem in the following 4 lines of code.

```
case class Product(id: Int, tags: Set[String])
val productList = List(Product(0, Set("a")), Product(1, Set("a", "b")))
// Create a dict mapping from a tag to a list of product
val tagDict = productList.flatMap(p => p.tags.map(_ -> p)).groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2))
println(tagDict("a") eq tagDict("a"))
```

It seems that each time `tagDict("a")` gives me a different object.
IMO, once the map is built, the value of the key `a` should be fixed.
Thank you.

Comment: that's because `mapValues` creates proxy `MappedValues` implementing `get` method which applies your function `_.map(_._2)` each time you call `apply` which calls `get` in its turn.

Comment: you can add `.toList.toMap` at the end of you `tagDict` builder line and this will fix the issue, but this is just a quick fix

Comment: or add `.view.force` instead